# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' In my Python Bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

The exact error I'm getting is

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 25, in on_member_join
    await myChannel.send(myGif)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 25, in on_member_join
    await myChannel.send(myGif)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

and my code goes as follows

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

myGif = 'https://media1.tenor.com/images/0c18696fab6bef37e72aa27ea1c4ebfc/tenor.gif?itemid=5288782'
myChannel = client.get_channel(850011208953102349)

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
  print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event 
async def on_member_join(member):
  await myChannel.send(myGif)

client.run(os.environ['myRunToken'])
```

I know for a fact im copying the right idea for the general channel I want the bot to go in and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong at this point

Comment: Looks like myChannel is empty, can you check that client.get_channel(channel_id) works ?

Comment: Turns out the channel was empty and all I needed to do was define myChannel under the on_member_join